# Getting the id of <a> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have to create 'a' tags dynamically when the function (lect) get called! And on the onclick() event of this tag, i need to know the id of it. Here is the code that is explaning problem more clearly

```
function lect(j) {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("cd" + j);

    var count = 3;
    for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
      var aTag = document.createElement('a');
      var inn = "analysis" + k;
      var id = "link" + k;
      var hr = "#";
      aTag.setAttribute('id', id);
      aTag.setAttribute('href', hr);
      aTag.innerHTML = inn;
      aTag.onclick = function (e) 
      { // here i want to get the id of tag, so that it could be passed to
        // the second html page  
        location.href = 'gallery-2.html?lectName=' + //name of id// ;
      };
    mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
    }
}
```

Please help me how should i do it!

Comment: `this` inside a listener on `aTag` will be `aTag`, unless the listener is bound/otherwise modified. If you don't want to use `this`, you'll need to use another function to create a closure for `k`.

Comment: `console.log(aTag.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
aTag.onclick = function (e) 
{
   location.href = 'gallery-2.html?lectName=' + this.id;
};
```

Within your `onclick` event, `this` will refer to the `aTag` object.